# Ruby on Rails - Cannot change Ruby version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rbenv

I'm a begginer of Programming.
I cannot change Ruby version.

The following is my Ruby version.

`ruby -v`

`ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-darwin14.0]`

But, The followig command returns error because of wrong Ruby version.

`rails generate scaffold User name:string email:string`

`Your Ruby version is 2.0.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.2`

If you can solve the problem, Please tell me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try: bundle exec rails generate scaffold User name:string email:string.   Also, are you using rvm?  It sounds like you have be set to the wrong ruby version.  Try 'rvm list' and see what it tells you is the current version of ruby that it's using.

Comment: >J Plato Thank you for your replaying. solved the problem with 'bundle exec rails generate scaffold User name:string email:string'. By the way,  what does it mean 'bundle exec'?

Comment: Basically, it means "execute the following command using the gems that are specified in my Gemfile".  You may have more than 1 version of any particular gem, because gems can be installed system-wide ("gem install somegem") and via your project's Gemfile (installed when you did "bundle install").  http://bundler.io/man/bundle-exec.1.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using rvm or rbenv? Check for the current version. To change current version do `rvm use 2.1.2` or `rbenv local 2.1.2` or create a `.ruby-version` file with `2.1.2` in it.

Comment: Thank you for your replying. Fortunately, I solve the problem ;)